# SQL for non english character insert error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to import an SQL file with non english characters.

Below is the content of the SQL file.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `thebook` (
    `Book`  int(2),
    `Chapter` INTEGER,
    `Versecount` INTEGER,
    `verse` varchar(1024)
);
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,1,'आरम्भमा परमेश्वरले आकाश र पृथ्वी सृष्टि गर्नु भयो।');
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,2,'पृथ्वी शून्य थियो, पृथ्वीमा केही पनि थिएन। समुद्रलाई अँध्यारोले ढाकेको थियो अनि परमेश्वरको आत्मा पानीमाथि परिभ्रमण गरिरहन्थ्यो।');
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,3,'तब परमेश्वरले भन्नुभयो, “उज्यालो होस्!” अनि उज्यालो चम्कन थाल्यो।');
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,4,'परमेश्वरले उज्यालो देख्नु भयो अनि त्यसलाई असल मान्नु भयो। तब परमेश्वरले उज्यालो र अँध्यारोलाई छुट्याउनु भयो।');
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,5,'परमेश्वरले उज्यालोलाई “दिन” र अँध्यारोलाई “रात” नाउँ दिनु भयो।साँझ पर्यो अनि बिहान भयो। यो पहिलो दिन थियो।');
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,6,'तब परमेश्वरले भन्नुभयो, “पानीलाई दुइ भाग पार्न त्यहाँ बतास होस्!”');
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,7,'यसर्थ परमेश्वरले त्यहाँ बतास सृष्टि गर्नुभयो अनि पानी छुट्टियो। केही पानी बतासमाथि रहयो अनि केही पानी बतास मुनि।');
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,8,'परमेश्वरले त्यस बतासलाई “आकाश” नाउँ दिनु भयो। साँझ पर्यो अनि बिहान भयो। यो दोस्रो दिन थियो।तेस्रो दिन - सुख्खा भूमि र उद्भिद');
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,9,'तब परमेश्वरले भन्नुभयो, “आकाश मुनिको पानी एकै ठाउँमा जम्मा होस्, र त्यहाँ सुख्खा भूमि देखियोस्।” अनि त्यस्तै भयो।');
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,10,'त्यो सुख्खा भूमिलाई परमेश्वरले “पृथ्वी” नाउँ राख्नु भयो। अनि एकै ठाउँमा जम्मा भएको पानीलाई “समुद्र” नाउँ राख्नु भयो। परमेश्वरलाई यस्तो भएकोमा असल लाग्यो।');
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,11,'तब परमेश्वरले भन्नुभयो, “पृथ्वीमा घाँस, अन्न उत्पन्न गर्ने उद्भिद तथा फल हुने बोटहरु उम्रियोस्। फल-रूखहरुले बीउ भएका फल फलाउने छन्। अनि प्रत्येक रूखले आफ्नै जातिका बीउ उब्जाउनेछ। यी उद्भिदहरू पृथवीमा उम्रिउन्।” अनि यस्तै भयो।');
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,12,'पृथ्वीमा घाँस र उद्भिदहरू उम्रे अनि अन्नहरू फले। अनि पृथ्वीमा फलभित्र बीउहरु हुने फल फल्ने रुखहरु उम्रिए। प्रत्येक उद्भिदले आफ्नै प्रकारको बीउहरु सिर्जना गरे। अनि परमेश्वरले यिनलाई देखेर असल मान्नु भयो।');
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,13,'साँझ पर्यो अनि बिहान भयो। यो तेस्रो दिन थियो।');
COMMIT;
```

To me, it looks like the syntax is correct but I am getting an error near the non english characters.

```
Error
SQL query:

INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,1,'आरम्भमा परमेश्वरले आकाश र पृथ्वी सृष्टि गर्नु भयो।')
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"thebook" VALUES(0,1,1,'आरम्भमा परमेश्वरले आ' at line 1
```

Anyone knows how to deal with this problem for SQL containing non english contents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the double quotes around the identifier

```
INSERT INTO "thebook" VALUES(0,1,1,'...
            ^       ^
```

We can either leave the identifier (i.e. the table name) unescaped, or we can replace the double quotes with the MySQL standard backticks. As demonstrated in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

```
INSERT INTO `thebook` VALUES(0,1,1,'...
            ^       ^
```

---

The default `sql_mode` causes MySQL to recognize tokens enclosed in double quotes as string literals. To get MySQL to recognize double quotes around identifiers, we'd need to include `ANSI_QUOTES` in `sql_mode`.

---

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

> `ANSI_QUOTES`
>
> Treat " as an identifier quote character (like the ` quote character) and not as a string quote character. You can still use ` to quote identifiers with this mode enabled. With ANSI_QUOTES enabled, you cannot use double quotation marks to quote literal strings because they are interpreted as identifiers.